# Images pulled from url not appearing on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, url, uiimageview

I wrote an app which goes and gets the url of an image from a RSS feed and displays it in a UIImageView and I know the image that I am pulling is valid because the url of the image goes straight to my label which shows the url and i typed it in and it goes to a image. It is a jpg image. What is annoying is that any image doesn't work even if I manually enter an url for an image.

This is my code , the image view code is down the bottom.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_world.rss"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    // Assuming data is in UTF8.
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    titleLabelLatestNews.text = string;


    NSString *webString = titleLabelLatestNews.text;
    NSScanner *stringScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:webString];
    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] init];
    while ([stringScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"url=\"" intoString:Nil];
        [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"/>" intoString:&content];

        NSString *filteredImage = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"url=\"" withString:@""];
        NSString *filteredImage2 = [filteredImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
        titleLabelLatestNews.text = filteredImage2;

        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filteredImage2];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [imageView setImage:image];



    }
```

The code I am using for the imageView -

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filteredImage2];
            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [imageView setImage:image];
```

Is it because of JPG?
Is it because of my ImageView?
Everything is linked up and everything is working fine except this I have seen all posts on how to get image from url and I tried everything but nothing seems to work the image view stays blank and white.

Summary :
I am pulling a image link from a website and the link is valid because I tested it and any other image i try downloading and putting in the image view also doesn't work the image view is blank and shows nothing at all.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: imageData contains something? Did you check if it's not nil? (Just asking you know)

Comment: Wait a second I will check

Comment: OMG it returns nil ok how do I fix this? @Avi Tsadok

Comment: First of all, check if the url of the image return something. Just put it in the browser.

Comment: Oh, just saw the you checked it. wait

Comment: Thanks ok I will wait

Comment: Thank you for your help, if you fix this your amaazzzinngnnnn!
!
!

Comment: Ok, if you check this url is valid (Check it again - print it to the console and make sure there is an image over there), check if it's not HTTPS by accident. After that, try to replace it with [NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL] although it's the same as the one you did, but just in case.

Comment: You can also use NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download a file. But the NSData should work...

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you show how to use NSURLSessionDownloadTask in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you don't see an image, because imageData is nil.
imageData is nil, because imageURL is also nil.

You need to escape the url string before you create NSURL.

Instead of :

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filteredImage2];
```

Do:

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[filteredImage2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Amazing news it didn't work :( `NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[filteredImage2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: imageURL ];
                              
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];`

Comment: For me it worked - I saw the images. Debug it step by step and tell me what is the problem. what NSURL contains? what NSData contains?

Comment: WAITT!T!T!T!T!TT!T!T!

Comment: Great to hear that. :)

Comment: In the end I will tell you that I am 12 years old and sorry for all the trouble that I caused! lol. I always run into problems like this I would love to have someone older and more experienced than me to help me - this is my email : programmer75@rocketmail.com if you want could you email me :D Thanks! @AviTsadok

Comment: And I did that too.....:) It was because of those damn hyphens , they needed to be encoded

Answer (score 0):

To download a file using NSURLSession, do something like that:

```
 NSURLSession *downloadFileSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask =[downloadFileSession downloadTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

// handle the response. 'location' is the file you downloaded

}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

But again, NSData should do the job. Re-check the url of the image, just before you start download it. You are modifying the url, so make sure it is valid.

Comment: do you mean [downloadTask resume];

Comment: Its funny any link even if I add manually it doesn't work, could you please copy paste the code into your project and try see what the error is thanks so much for your help though

Comment: check if you are getting the url of image properly in the  while  loop

Comment: Did you re-check the url? And what do you mean 'didn't work'? If the url is valid, it doesn't make sense..

Comment: Let me check it. Wait :)

Comment: thats is my concern exactly even try this image -

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Benz-velo.jpg/747px-Benz-velo.jpg

Comment: @Debanjan Chakraborty Yes I have I made it so the string is shown in a label so It shows the link and I even typed it out and it doesn't work see I tried going on wikipedia grabbing random image getting link and then pasting instead of filteredImage2 but it still doesn't work!!!!!

Comment: I used the wikipedia url in http://pastebin.com/GPQzq5xD and the image appeared. But when I used http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/141215181325-18-what-a-shot-1216-top-tease.jpg, the image didn't appear.

Comment: @debanjanChakraborty, please see the final answer above

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a rudimentary code, I think I solved it

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100)];
[imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_world.rss"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

// Assuming data is in UTF8.
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];


NSScanner *stringScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] init];
while ([stringScanner isAtEnd] == NO)
{
    [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"url=\"" intoString:Nil];
    [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"/>" intoString:&content];

    NSString *filteredImage = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"url=\"" withString:@""];
    NSString *filteredImage2 = [filteredImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ // 1
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[filteredImage2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 2

            if(imgData)
            {
                UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                if(img)
                {
                    [imgView setImage:img];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@" image url was %@ ",filteredImage2);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                 NSLog(@" image url was %@ ",filteredImage2);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Lol this looks so complicated, the accepted answer is quite easy. But thanks for your input . Only if i had enough reputation to vote up

Comment: :) Cheers for a 12 yr old IOS developer

Comment: Thanks! I used your example as well and it worked :)

Comment: It's same principle of @Avi Tsadok...... the damn hyphens in the url needed to be encoded